# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle

I am building an app that needs to connect to a Google app engine backend built in python. However every time i build the app i get this error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I ran the build with --stacktrace and --info and got this

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"5 errors; aborting","sources":[{}]}
```

The build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.testapp"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
    }
}
repositories {
maven {
    url 'http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo'
}
mavenCentral()
mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile project(':app:libs:customerapi')

compile([group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.20.0'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

I have no clue what is happening and could not find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your android closure in build.gradle:

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Answer found on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/r4p-sBLl7DQ

The problem is that java runs out of memory during the gradle compilation. Increasing the heap size will raise the memory ceiling, allowing the compilation to complete successfully. Do you need to increase the heap to 4GB? No. But increasing it solved the problem I was having -- which happened to be the same as the original poster.